# Override DbContext when returning IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, iqueryable

In my database, all my tables have 5 repeating fields (CreateUser, UpdateUser, IsRemoved...)

Now, I call the DbContext normally as:

```
mydbEntities db = new mydbEntities();
```

And then when I need to bring up all the `students` and all `classes` I call them normally as:

```
var students = db.students;
var classes = db.classes;
```

BUT! Since I have to NOT bring the ones that have column `IsRemoved == true` , I'm rewriting everywhere in my app to:

```
var students = db.students.Where(m => m.IsRemoved == false);
var classes = db.classes.Where(m => m.IsRemoved == false);
```

To avoid bugs and errors when replacing existing code, when the scaffolding creates new controllers, and other developers forgetting to add the Where(), makes me wonder if I can overwrite the call `db.students` so that internally, it ALWAYS adds the Where()

This will also help in the future, so when I call `db.students.Include(s => s.classes)` that both times the `IsRemoved` is taken into account and even if the student exists, if the class has been removed, then it won't return it in the list.

Answer (score 2):

This is why I believe that having Repository classes - for the database access layer - is always a good idea. So you never have to access your `dbContext` object directly, but through a layer of abstraction, eg. the StudentRepositoy.

```
IStudentRepository studentRepository = new StudentRepository(dbContext);
var students = studentRepository.getStudents();
```

In this case, you only need to add the `Where(m => m.IsRemoved == false)` once, inside your `getStudents()` method.

I hope you don't have those queries repeated in your controllers (I don't know if you are using MVC or some other thing). Check out [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-the-repository-pattern-with-asp.net-mvc-and-entity-framework.htm) tutorial for more detail information.

Although, this does not answer your question, I hope you consider these modifications.

Edit:
It does look like there is a way to override dbcontext from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I like that idea and can't believe I didn't think of it. I'm use them quite extensively in my projects.

Comment: I have used in many MVC projects, it is awesome! :) @AndyEvans

Comment: yes, I'm using MVC. I would have to modify the templates to use the repository pattern.  I'm gonna look first into the documentation and then test the repository pattern.

Comment: cool @elcool. Feel free to select this or any other as "the" answer once you finish testing (green check)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating a view in the database that accounts for the IsRemoved flag?

```
Select * From <tablename> Where IsRemoved = 0
```

Then add the view to your DBContext.

Just an idea.

Comment: sounds like a smart idea to me, keep it simple :D

Comment: I'd have double everything.  I'll run a test and see